# Soft Question about Möbius Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, soft-question, mobius-transformation

Very soft question and I may be completely wrong about this, but does it make any sense to think about the Möbius transformation matrix as a change of basis for $\mathbb C$?

Comment: C being the complex plane here

Comment: Hint: Is that matrix a non-sigular one...?

Comment: yeah, since det(A) will always be nonzero, in order for it to be a mobious transf.

Comment: And a square matrix determines a change of basis (taking it as a linear map) iff it is non-sigular, thus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Möbius transformation is not a linear transformation of $\Bbb{C}$ even if the associated matrix might have other action on the space. Hence, the Möbius transformation matrix should not be thought of as a basis change for $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: OK, thanks, told you I might be waay off

Comment: Humans can always think of something as something else.  That's imagination!  Otherwise you could say that *no, no, a matrix is an $n\times n$ array of numbers, it has nothing to do with a linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$...*